# create a clean if with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I basically want to perform a `switch()` or `if()` in the cleanest way possible with jQuery based on the following HTML code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#core" data-toggle="tab">Core Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#parallel" data-toggle="tab">Parallel settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cron_settings" data-toggle="tab">Cron limit settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's kind of an example in which I'm trying to perform

```
switch(".nav nav-tabs li > active") {
    case "#core":

    break;
    case "#parallel":

    break;
    case "#cron_settings":

    break;
}
```

That syntax is obviously not the correct way, it's just an example of how I'd like to be able to perform such `switch` or `if`

So, what is the cleanest and neatest way of doing so?

**UPDATED EDIT**

I've tried to use the following **answer** inside my code to no avail

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active a").each(function(this){
        switch(this.href) {
            case "#core":
                alert("you're using the core tab");
            break;
            case "#parallel":
                alert("you're using the parallel tab");
            break;
            case "#cron_settings":
                alert("you're using the cron settings tab");
            break;  
        }
     })
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to find out if that selector has that associated class?

Comment: @JustinWood, yes that's correct

Comment: Should be `function(){` not `function(this){` .

Comment: how are you using this? SHould be easier ways to integrate with your tabs code using tabs plugin events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix up your selector a bit, so try this out:

```
$("ul.nav.nav-tabs li.active a").each(function(){
    switch(this.href) {
       case ...
    }
});
```

In your case you *might* want to use `this.hash` instead.

Comment: If it's a typical tab design, only one can be active at a time, so you don't need `.each()`.

Comment: @Barmar I have no idea where he doing this selection. The OP can do what he wants :-)

Comment: Thanks @Krishna Did not notice that.

Comment: That's a beautiful way to format, thank you very much, I'll award once the 9 minutes have passed (award accepted answer limit)

Comment: No problem @Curtis Happy to help :-D

Comment: @qwertynl I've came across a problem with your code, I'll update my answer if you don't mind checking

Comment: Ummm do not do `function(this)` That makes no sense and you probably see an error in your code....

Comment: I tried with and without `this` and it's still not alerting anything

Comment: Did you check what `this.href` contained?

Comment: @qwertynl, that explains it all, it's showing the full URL of my browser for some reason? including my site url, anyway to avoid that?

Comment: @Curtis Try using `this.hash` instead of `this.href`